# mongodb's aggregate lookup pipeline condition collection

Tags: mongodb

I have to retrieve male student's details of all the schools when I wrote the query which is retrieving both male and female students.

```
      let result = await schoolModel.aggregate([
        { $match: { isdeleted: false } },
        { $lookup: {
                localField: "_id", from: "students", foreignField: "schl_id", as: "studentsList" },
        { $project: { "studentsList.isdeleted": 1, "studentsList.gender": 1, "studentsList._id": 1 } },
        { $match: { "studentsList.isdeleted": false, "studentsList.gender": "Male" } }
    ]);
```

**Here in the above query it is not checking the match condition ie.., studentsList.isdeleted & gender Can anyone help me in what's wrong with the above query**

Answer (score 1):

$lookup returns an Array meaning when you use your match query it returns true if the array contains a document that match your conditions.

To retreive just the results you want you got two options:

1. To [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `studentList` match per document and then group to restructure the result.
2. A little more elegant way of using Mongo's v3.6+ of [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries).

It would look a little something like this:

```js
let result = await schoolModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      isdeleted: false
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'students',
      let: { school_id: '$_id' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ['$schl_id', '$$school_id'] },
                { $eq: ['$gender', 'Male'] },
                { $eq: ['$isdeleted', false] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: 'studentList'
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { 'studentList.0': { $exists: true } }
  }
]);
```